# How stop reading data in AnyEvent

Tags: perl, anyevent

I've been doing some proxy script using Perl's [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent).

```
Agent<->Proxy-Server<->client
```

My program acts as the proxy server in this setup.

In [AnyEvent::Handle](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Handle), How can I stop reading data from the agent and resume after client gets the data?.

Part code:

```
$hdl->on_read( 
    sub {
        my $h = shift;
        $h->stop_read;
        print $h->rbuf;
        $h->push_write("Hello there");
    }
);
```

I recently added `$handle->stop_read` in agent `on_read` event but that doesn't work. The agent always get the data.

Comment: yes..my program is the proxy server.